# Why the outputs of spectrogram between python and MATLAB are greatly different?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, matplotlib, matplotlib.mlab

I am trying to translate a MATLAB script into a python script. However, I got completely different outputs from the MATLAB spectrogram and the matplotlib.mlab.specgram(). I checked other questions, however, they didn't help my problem. Could you please check my code?

**MATLAB code**

```
nfft = 2048;
window = hamming(nfft);
noverlap = nfft * 0.75;
X = spectrogram(data, window, noverlap, nfft);
X_abs = abs(X);
```

**MATLAB result**
(First 3 time (columns) and 6 frequency (rows) of X_abs)

```
30.1724220846775    31.0947120708528    34.6189241212563
12.2846967449186    12.9514893948274    13.8107010563694
1.20537039658088    0.614575979921346   0.724643190160887
3.49625399374313    2.48394521607334    1.43848016399582
2.83227523082322    1.76662351483948    2.35189645650400
0.568257664015496   0.743800152833193   1.78240372417488
```

**Python code**

```
fs = 10000
nfft = 2048
window = numpy.hamming(nfft)
noverlap = int(nfft * 0.75)
X, _, _  = matplotlib.mlab.specgram(data, Fs=fs, window=window, noverlap=noverlap, NFFT=nfft)
X_abs = numpy.abs(X)
```

**Python result**
(First 3 time (columns) and 6 frequency (rows) of X_abs)

```
1.11910601e-04    1.18856779e-04    1.47325530e-04
1.15646041e-02    1.17253708e-02    1.17148462e-02
3.71030621e-05    4.12401562e-05    4.68934648e-05
4.22107583e-03    4.31724420e-03    4.36301850e-03
3.57208608e-07    9.28607182e-08    1.29100910e-07
8.98671692e-08    1.93129250e-07    5.93981935e-07
```

As you can see, they output completely different values...I am not sure why they do. Could I ask for any advice or comment?

Comment: Are these the same data?

Comment: You should at the least specify Fs for the matlab call.  You should also check how each function normalizes the spectra.  There are different conventions.

Comment: @Jody Klymak Thank you so much for your comments. Of course, I used the same data. Additionally, I tried `fs = 10000; X = spectrogram(data, window, noverlap, nfft, fs, 'yaxis');`. However, it didn;t work. I mean I got the same output values.

Comment: all I can suggest is read the docs for the normalizations. i.e. `mode` for matplotlib, and `spectrumtype` for matlab

Comment: @Jody Klymak Finally, I got almost the same output values from Python and MATLAB. I added `mode='magnitude'` as an additional argument in the Python code. Additionally, I divided the MATLAB outputs by the maximum value to implement the normalization. Thank you so much for your help!